# Kafka Consumer keeps rebalancing

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

My Kafka Consumer client keeps rebalancing between frequent polls even if no source records are being processed.

Also, I have `consumer.pause()` and `consumer.resume()` implemented on the right place to hold the consumer from polling until the polled number of consumer records are processed on isolation with the backend APIs. Not sure what is causing the issue.

**Consumer logs**

```
2022-07-21 10:27:08; LOG_LEVEL="INFO"; SOURCE="MyKAFKAConsumer"; PLATFORM="Retail_Products"; SERVICE="MyKAFKAConsumer"; EVENT_MESSAGE="**Polling...**"

2022-07-21 10:27:25; LOG_LEVEL="INFO"; SOURCE="MyKAFKAConsumer"; PLATFORM="Retail_Products"; SERVICE="MyKAFKAConsumer"; EVENT_MESSAGE="**Polling...**"

2022-07-21 10:27:25; LOG_LEVEL="INFO"; SOURCE="org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator"; PLATFORM="Retail_Products"; SERVICE="MyKAFKAConsumer"; EVENT_MESSAGE="[Consumer clientId=MyKAFKAConsumerClientId1, groupId=MyKAFKAConsumeGroupId1] Group coordinator brokerHost:9093 (id: 2147444144 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid due to cause: session timed out without receiving a heartbeat response.isDisconnected: false. Rediscovery will be attempted."

2022-07-21 10:27:25; LOG_LEVEL="INFO"; SOURCE="org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator"; PLATFORM="Retail_Products"; SERVICE="MyKAFKAConsumer"; EVENT_MESSAGE="[Consumer clientId=MyKAFKAConsumerClientId1, groupId=MyKAFKAConsumeGroupId1] Discovered group coordinator brokerHost:9093 (id: 2147444144 rack: null)"

2022-07-21 10:27:25; LOG_LEVEL="INFO"; SOURCE="org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator"; PLATFORM="Retail_Products"; SERVICE="MyKAFKAConsumer"; EVENT_MESSAGE="[Consumer clientId=MyKAFKAConsumerClientId1, groupId=MyKAFKAConsumeGroupId1] Discovered group coordinator brokerHost:9093 (id: 2147444144 rack: null)"

2022-07-21 10:27:25; LOG_LEVEL="ERROR"; SOURCE="org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator"; PLATFORM="Retail_Products"; SERVICE="MyKAFKAConsumer"; EVENT_MESSAGE="[Consumer clientId=MyKAFKAConsumerClientId1, groupId=MyKAFKAConsumeGroupId1] Offset commit failed on partition MySourceTopic-0 at offset 38572: The coordinator is not aware of this member."

2022-07-21 10:27:25; LOG_LEVEL="INFO"; SOURCE="org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator"; PLATFORM="Retail_Products"; SERVICE="MyKAFKAConsumer"; EVENT_MESSAGE="[Consumer clientId=MyKAFKAConsumerClientId1, groupId=MyKAFKAConsumeGroupId1] OffsetCommit failed with Generation{generationId=18661, memberId='MyKAFKAConsumerClientId1-d410deb4-d6f9-4f7e-b789-f866b89817e6', protocol='range'}: The coordinator is not aware of this member."

2022-07-21 10:27:25; LOG_LEVEL="WARN"; SOURCE="org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator"; PLATFORM="Retail_Products"; SERVICE="MyKAFKAConsumer"; EVENT_MESSAGE="[Consumer clientId=MyKAFKAConsumerClientId1, groupId=MyKAFKAConsumeGroupId1] Asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {MySourceTopic-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=38572, leaderEpoch=132, metadata=''}, MySourceTopic-2=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=38566, leaderEpoch=122, metadata=''}, MySourceTopic-1=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=38779, leaderEpoch=118, metadata=''}, MySourceTopic-3=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=38585, leaderEpoch=121, metadata=''}} failed: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records."

2022-07-21 10:27:25; LOG_LEVEL="INFO"; SOURCE="org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator"; PLATFORM="Retail_Products"; SERVICE="MyKAFKAConsumer"; EVENT_MESSAGE="[Consumer clientId=MyKAFKAConsumerClientId1, groupId=MyKAFKAConsumeGroupId1] Failing OffsetCommit request since the consumer is not part of an active group"

2022-07-21 10:27:25; LOG_LEVEL="INFO"; SOURCE="org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator"; PLATFORM="Retail_Products"; SERVICE="MyKAFKAConsumer"; EVENT_MESSAGE="[Consumer clientId=MyKAFKAConsumerClientId1, groupId=MyKAFKAConsumeGroupId1] Attempt to heartbeat with stale Generation{generationId=18661, memberId='MyKAFKAConsumerClientId1-d410deb4-d6f9-4f7e-b789-f866b89817e6', protocol='range'} and group instance id Optional.empty failed due to UNKNOWN_MEMBER_ID, ignoring the error"

2022-07-21 10:27:25; LOG_LEVEL="WARN"; SOURCE="org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator"; PLATFORM="Retail_Products"; SERVICE="MyKAFKAConsumer"; EVENT_MESSAGE="[Consumer clientId=MyKAFKAConsumerClientId1, groupId=MyKAFKAConsumeGroupId1] Synchronous auto-commit of offsets {MySourceTopic-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=38572, leaderEpoch=132, metadata=''}, MySourceTopic-2=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=38566, leaderEpoch=122, metadata=''}, MySourceTopic-1=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=38779, leaderEpoch=118, metadata=''}, MySourceTopic-3=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=38585, leaderEpoch=121, metadata=''}} failed: Offset commit cannot be completed since the consumer is not part of an active group for auto partition assignment; it is likely that the consumer was kicked out of the group."

2022-07-21 10:27:25; LOG_LEVEL="INFO"; SOURCE="org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator"; PLATFORM="Retail_Products"; SERVICE="MyKAFKAConsumer"; EVENT_MESSAGE="[Consumer clientId=MyKAFKAConsumerClientId1, groupId=MyKAFKAConsumeGroupId1] Giving away all assigned partitions as lost since generation has been reset,indicating that consumer is no longer part of the group"

2022-07-21 10:27:25; LOG_LEVEL="INFO"; SOURCE="org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator"; PLATFORM="Retail_Products"; SERVICE="MyKAFKAConsumer"; EVENT_MESSAGE="[Consumer clientId=MyKAFKAConsumerClientId1, groupId=MyKAFKAConsumeGroupId1] Lost previously assigned partitions MySourceTopic-0, MySourceTopic-2, MySourceTopic-1, MySourceTopic-3"

2022-07-21 10:27:25; LOG_LEVEL="INFO"; SOURCE="org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator"; PLATFORM="Retail_Products"; SERVICE="MyKAFKAConsumer"; EVENT_MESSAGE="[Consumer clientId=MyKAFKAConsumerClientId1, groupId=MyKAFKAConsumeGroupId1] (Re-)joining group"
2022-07-21 10:27:25; LOG_LEVEL="INFO"; SOURCE="org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator"; PLATFORM="Retail_Products"; SERVICE="MyKAFKAConsumer"; EVENT_MESSAGE="[Consumer clientId=MyKAFKAConsumerClientId1, groupId=MyKAFKAConsumeGroupId1] (Re-)joining group"

2022-07-21 10:27:26; LOG_LEVEL="INFO"; SOURCE="org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator"; PLATFORM="Retail_Products"; SERVICE="MyKAFKAConsumer"; EVENT_MESSAGE="[Consumer clientId=MyKAFKAConsumerClientId1, groupId=MyKAFKAConsumeGroupId1] Successfully joined group with generation Generation{generationId=18663, memberId='MyKAFKAConsumerClientId1-f55c7204-c932-40cd-a9b3-0351f9904026', protocol='range'}"

2022-07-21 10:27:26; LOG_LEVEL="INFO"; SOURCE="org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator"; PLATFORM="Retail_Products"; SERVICE="MyKAFKAConsumer"; EVENT_MESSAGE="[Consumer clientId=MyKAFKAConsumerClientId1, groupId=MyKAFKAConsumeGroupId1] Successfully synced group in generation Generation{generationId=18663, memberId='MyKAFKAConsumerClientId1-f55c7204-c932-40cd-a9b3-0351f9904026', protocol='range'}"

2022-07-21 10:27:26; LOG_LEVEL="INFO"; SOURCE="org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator"; PLATFORM="Retail_Products"; SERVICE="MyKAFKAConsumer"; EVENT_MESSAGE="[Consumer clientId=MyKAFKAConsumerClientId1, groupId=MyKAFKAConsumeGroupId1] Notifying assignor about the new Assignment(partitions=[MySourceTopic-0, MySourceTopic-1, MySourceTopic-2, MySourceTopic-3])"

2022-07-21 10:27:26; LOG_LEVEL="INFO"; SOURCE="org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator"; PLATFORM="Retail_Products"; SERVICE="MyKAFKAConsumer"; EVENT_MESSAGE="[Consumer clientId=MyKAFKAConsumerClientId1, groupId=MyKAFKAConsumeGroupId1] Adding newly assigned partitions: MySourceTopic-0, MySourceTopic-2, MySourceTopic-1, MySourceTopic-3"

2022-07-21 10:27:26; LOG_LEVEL="INFO"; SOURCE="org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator"; PLATFORM="Retail_Products"; SERVICE="MyKAFKAConsumer"; EVENT_MESSAGE="[Consumer clientId=MyKAFKAConsumerClientId1, groupId=MyKAFKAConsumeGroupId1] Setting offset for partition MySourceTopic-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=38572, offsetEpoch=Optional[132], currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[brokerHost:9093 (id: 33708 rack: null)], epoch=132}}"

2022-07-21 10:27:26; LOG_LEVEL="INFO"; SOURCE="org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator"; PLATFORM="Retail_Products"; SERVICE="MyKAFKAConsumer"; EVENT_MESSAGE="[Consumer clientId=MyKAFKAConsumerClientId1, groupId=MyKAFKAConsumeGroupId1] Setting offset for partition MySourceTopic-2 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=38566, offsetEpoch=Optional[122], currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[brokerHost:9093 (id: 39217 rack: null)], epoch=122}}"

2022-07-21 10:27:26; LOG_LEVEL="INFO"; SOURCE="org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator"; PLATFORM="Retail_Products"; SERVICE="MyKAFKAConsumer"; EVENT_MESSAGE="[Consumer clientId=MyKAFKAConsumerClientId1, groupId=MyKAFKAConsumeGroupId1] Setting offset for partition MySourceTopic-1 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=38779, offsetEpoch=Optional[118], currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[brokerHost:9093 (id: 30678 rack: null)], epoch=118}}"

2022-07-21 10:27:26; LOG_LEVEL="INFO"; SOURCE="org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator"; PLATFORM="Retail_Products"; SERVICE="MyKAFKAConsumer"; EVENT_MESSAGE="[Consumer clientId=MyKAFKAConsumerClientId1, groupId=MyKAFKAConsumeGroupId1] Setting offset for partition MySourceTopic-3 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=38585, offsetEpoch=Optional[121], currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[brokerHost:9093 (id: 38300 rack: null)], epoch=121}}"

2022-07-21 10:27:30; LOG_LEVEL="INFO"; SOURCE="MyKAFKAConsumer"; PLATFORM="Retail_Products"; SERVICE="MyKAFKAConsumer"; EVENT_MESSAGE="**Polling...**"

2022-07-21 10:27:35; LOG_LEVEL="INFO"; SOURCE="MyKAFKAConsumer"; PLATFORM="Retail_Products"; SERVICE="MyKAFKAConsumer"; EVENT_MESSAGE="**Polling...**"
```

**Consumer Configuration**

```
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = earliest
    enable.auto.commit = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 100
```

**Consumer poll() implementation**

```java
        while (true) {
            try {
                ConsumerRecords<String, GenericRecord> records = null;
                LOGGER.info("Polling...{}");
                records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(5));

                if (records != null && records.count() > 0) {
                    consumer.pause(consumer.assignment());
                    recordExecutor.execute(records);
                }

                consumer.resume(consumer.assignment());
                consumer.commitSync();

            } catch (SerializationException e) {
                continue;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                continue;
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you mention the kafka clients version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

There are several points which I would like to mention here.

1. You should not ideally be using `consumer.pause()` and `consumer.resume()` for your use case. If there are no records, then the `consumer.poll()` will block for the duration specified in its parameter if no records are available. So, it should not cause any high CPU usage as it is not a non-blocking call.

From the docs of [consumer.poll()](https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html)

> This method returns immediately if there are records available.
> Otherwise, it will await the passed timeout. If the timeout expires,
> an empty record set will be returned.

2. `max.poll.interval.ms` is different from what you should be passing in the `consumer.poll()`. If both are same, `consumer.poll()` would not have this parameter in the first place. `max.poll.interval.ms` is the max. delay between invocations of poll.

   So, when there are no records, then you are waiting till `max.poll.interval.ms`, by the time next `poll()` calls. Since the next poll() is not made within this timeout, consumer is considered failed.

From the docs of [max.poll.interval.ms](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/consumer-configs.html#consumerconfigs_max.poll.interval.ms):

> If poll() is not called before expiration of this timeout, then the
> consumer is considered failed and **the group will rebalance** in order to
> reassign the partitions to another member

3. Also, you seem to be using `commitSync()` and your configuration is `enable.auto.commit=true`. You should ideally use either of them.
4. Log the exceptions in the catch block if you don't want to throw them.

Comment: Thank for your response, I have edited my question to records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(5). Earlier I have given wrong information. So basically, inside poll() I have given 5 Sec and the max.poll.interval.ms = 300000 (5 Mins). So basically, Rebalancing should not occur, as you can see my consumer log it is polling  every 5 seconds. But at the same time rebalancing is happening every five mins, that's the issue here.

Comment: @ChristDist Check if there are any other consumers in the group that are causing the rebalance.

Answer (score 0):

After an extensive analysis, we have identified the root cause of these frequent rebalancing, which was due to the session.timeout between the consumers/streamers and the Group Coordinator (Leader Broker) . The session.timeout is keep happening due to the server capacity issue (100 % CPU Utilization) where these consumers/streamers are hosted. When the CPU is saturated to 100 %, all of these KAFKA Clients are getting into a **Not Responding** state and eventually it's session timing out.

### Event log

group-MyKAFKAConsumeGroupId1] Group coordinator brokerHost:9093 (id: 21474 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid due to cause: **session timed out** without receiving a heartbeat response.isDisconnected: false. Rediscovery will be attempted.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue in one of my applications. As you can see from the logs, the error is

> 2022-07-21 10:27:25; LOG_LEVEL="INFO";
> SOURCE="org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator";
> PLATFORM="Retail_Products"; SERVICE="MyKAFKAConsumer";
> EVENT_MESSAGE="[Consumer clientId=MyKAFKAConsumerClientId1,
> groupId=MyKAFKAConsumeGroupId1] Group coordinator brokerHost:9093 (id:
> 2147444144 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid due to cause: session
> timed out without receiving a heartbeat response.isDisconnected:
> false. Rediscovery will be attempted."

This error ( strangely the Kafka consumer logs this under 'INFO' ) happens when you hit the session timeout on your kafka consumer i.e. the heartbeat from the kafka consumer heartbeat thread isn't received by the Group Coordinator within the specified time limit. In java the config property that determines this is 'session.timeout.ms'. Eventually, the commit for the kafka message would fail and your application would go through a rebalance. I faced this in my application and it was an annoying issue.

The interesting part is why we were facing this error in our applications in the first place. We memory-profiled the application using Java flight recorder and noted that there were always several long GC pauses around the time the session timeout used to happen. Moreover, we were using an older version of the kafka api in our application, and the default session timeout property then was a mere 10 seconds, now they have increased it to 45 seconds in recent versions.

Once I changed the session.timeout.ms property to 45 seconds, this error went away.